# Why do I can't use path when read

Tags: python

when I simply write the path of my folder in a variable it works, but when I read the path in simple txt files it doesn't work
Example :

`path = "path to a folder"`       it works

but when I use :

`path = lines[0]`                 it doesn't works

My application go read the first line of txt file where my path is stocked and then it should stock it in the path variable.

I tried to see if the path was read correctly and yes, if I print the path it was always good but it doesn't work.

```
txt=open('/Users/patrick/Desktop/config.txt','r')
lines = txt.readlines()
path = lines[0]
files = []

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
```

Comment: Try printing the path to see if it is showing the path or not.

Comment: Please elaborate "doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to strip `white spaces` and `\n` new line character because `readlines` returns lines including `\n`.

```
txt=open('/Users/patrick/Desktop/config.txt','r')
lines = [line.strip() for line in txt.readlines()]
path = lines[0]
files = []

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
```

Instead of using `readlines`, you can use `read` and `split` using `\n` character.

```
text = open('/Users/patrick/Desktop/config.txt','r').read()
lines = text.split("\n")
path = lines[0]
files = []

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`readline` leaves the trailing linefeed in the line. Use:

```
path = lines[0].strip()
```